# Add text to xyplot with panel.superpose

Tags: r, lattice

I've created a plot with `xyplot`, which must show two groups of dots and they're regression line.

```
xyplot(log(Vegetati)~log(Reprod),
       type=c("p", "r"),
       group=Espece,
       data=plantes,
       panel = "panel.superpose",
       auto.key =list(
         points = FALSE, 
         columns=2),
         xlab="log(modules végétatifs)",
         ylab="log(modules reproducteurs)",
        )
```

I would now add the equations of the two different regression lines, but I don't succeed at combine the `panel.superpose` function with a panel.text or other. 
Am I in the wrong way? I can't show the equation AND the two dot's groups with they're line.

Thanks! So, this is a reproductible exemple :

```
library(lattice)
data(iris)
xyplot(log(Sepal.Width)~log(Sepal.Length), type=c("p", "r"), group=Species,
    data=iris, panel = "panel.superpose")
```

EDIT : Problem solved! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! To improve your chances of getting an answer, please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). If you can't post (parts of) your own data, or simulate data, you can use any of data sets that comes with R (`library(help = "datasets")`). For a small plant example, please have a look at `iris`.

Comment: Thanks! So, this is a reproductible exemple :

library(lattice)

data(iris)

xyplot(log(Sepal.Width)~log(Sepal.Length),
       type=c("p", "r"),
       group=Species,
       data=iris,
       panel = "panel.superpose",
       auto.key =list(
         points = FALSE, 
         columns=2),
         xlab="log(modules végétatifs)",
         ylab="log(modules reproducteurs)",
)`

Comment: Thanks! Please update your _question_ with this example. Then it is much more visible to people that wants to help you, and it is easier to format nicely. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would write your own custom panel function that delegates to the panel functions you're interested in invoking

```
panel.my <- function(...) {
    panel.superpose(...)
    panel.text(1, 2, "shoe")  ## or ltext
}
```

and then use it

```
xyplot(log(Vegetati)~log(Reprod), type=c("p", "r"), group=Espece, data=plantes, 
    panel = panel.my)
```

The use of `...` passes all arguments seen by panel.my to panel.superpose; you might intercept specific arguments to know which panel you are in, etc., but more details would require that you provide an example that StackOverflow *participants* (not just you!) can reproduce, e.g., using one of the built-in data sets.

Comment: I got it!
Thank, you!